# Creating Powershell script to loop through excel file and create folders

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm new to Powerscript and looking at writing a solution to loop through an excel file and create a folder for each row in the file.

At the moment I have the following:

```
$objExcel = new-object -comobject excel.application 

$objExcel.Visible = $True 

$ExcelFilesLocation = “D:\Users\”

$UserWorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFilesLocation + “ProjectCodes.xlsx”) 

$UserWorksheet = $UserWorkBook.Worksheets.Item(1)

$intRow = 2

Do {

 $Projectcode = $UserWorksheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 1).Value()

 $pos = $userLogOnEmail.IndexOf(“@”)

           $intRow++

           } While ($UserWorksheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1).Value() -ne $null)

$objExcel.Quit()

$a = Release-Ref($UserWorksheet)

$a = Release-Ref($UserWorkBook) 

$a = Release-Ref($objExcel)
```

The idea is to loop through the project code column for each row. Then create a folder that is named for the project code.

Comment: Where's the part where you create the folders? What's the **specific** problem you're facing?

Comment: That is the problem I'm stuck on

Answer (score 1):

Having spent painful hours wrangling Excel COM objects with PowerShell, my advice is to give up! Office COM objects are confusing, unwieldy and slow.

Replace the technology you use to access Excel in PowerShell with something  better. For example, this module: https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel. You can use `Install-Module ImportExcel -Scope CurrentUser` if you're using PS 5.

Apart from being easier to use and much faster it doesn't require Excel to be installed, making your final script more portable.

Admitedly, you don't get full Excel functionality with this module but since you seem to be doing no more than reading cells, you should be fine.

Alternatively, Save your Excel file as CSV and use `Import-Csv` instead.

Comment: Excellent tip to use Import-Csv

Answer (score 0):

To create a new directory, use [New-Item](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849795.aspx)

For example, assuming `$Projectcode` is a string containing a valid path:

```
New-Item -Path $Projectcode -Type Directory
```